# look up for a parent record in the same table based on the list of boundary applied on another column

Tags: python, dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I have two dataframes one with a key and class family, another df with key and parent key
and the list of class families(consider this list as a boundary).
we need to find the parent that goes outside the boundary for each key in df1.

how do we achieve this in scala spark?

class family list [A,B,C]

df1:

| pmKey | classfamily |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | A |
| 222 | B |
| 333 | c |
| 444 | D |

df2:

| pmKey | parent_pmkey |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | 222 |
| 222 | 333 |
| 333 | 444 |
| 444 | 555 |

expected df:

| pmKey | classfamily | parent_pmkey |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | A | 444 |
| 222 | B | 444 |
| 333 | C | 444 |

Comment: I am not sure to get it. What's the logic that causes `parent_pmkey` to be `444` for `pmKey=111` ?